# Strip html in Angular template binding

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template

I have a list displaying data that can sometimes contain HTML

```
  <li *ngFor="let result of results">
    <span [innerHTML]="result.question.title">
    </span>
  </li>
```

The problem with using `innerHTML` is that the HTML gets parsed and rendered, so things like `<p>` tags will add margins and ruin the list's alignment.

I would like to strip all html tags and just output plain text.

An approach like this:

```
  <li *ngFor="let result of results">
    <span>
        {{result.question.title}}
    </span>
  </li>
```

does not strip the HTML, it just outputs the HTML as plain text.

How can I strip the HTML and leave plain text the 'Angular' way?

Comment: Is not "stripping the HTML" going to result in "plain text"? What exactly are you expecting? Perhaps you should show a sample and what you expect as a result. But usually, when you remove all HTML tags then all you are left with is "plain text". If you mean something else, then it needs a better explanation. Best shown by example as suggested.

Comment: @NeilLunn that is exactly what I mean. I am expecting plain text. I don't mean something else

Comment: Since I ( and I think others ) are under the impression that the markup would be sanitized and removed instead, then again as was suggested "show us a reproducible sample" instead of just talking about it.

Comment: The Impression you are under is correct.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I guess there is no direct way to strip HTML tags from string, you can use [Pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes), write a "Pipe" like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'striphtml'
})

export class StripHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string): any {
        return value.replace(/<.*?>/g, ''); // replace tags
    }
}
```

then add "StripHtmlPipe" to your module "declarations", after these steps you can use this pipe in your HTML:

```
<li *ngFor="let result of results">
    <span>
        {{result.question.title | striphtml}}
    </span>
  </li>
```

please note that the code above is not fully tested.

Comment: in case that doesn't work, try `<span [innerHTML]="content | striphtml"></span>`

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 13):

I wouldn't recommend using a regex to parse html as suggested by
kite.js.org. Use the browsers `textContent` / `innerText` function instead:

```
htmlToText(html: string) {
    const tmp = document.createElement('DIV');
    tmp.innerHTML = html;
    return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || '';
}
```

This should be much more reliable. You can still use a pipe if you like, just don't use regex to parse html!