# (Angular) PrimeNG table, disable/hide HTML tags in cell (Quill.js)

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, quill, primeng-table

I cannot seem to hide HTML tags in PrimeNG table that is being edited with Quill.js. Is there a setting to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this using angular **stripHtml** custom Pipe:

[Strip html in Angular template binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46271749/9712178)